# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename') nodejs --multer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload, frontend, multer

I'm currently trying to make the user can edit their profile picture, I'm using nodejs, react & multer for that. On the other hand I receive an error when I send my form, I show you my code I hope you can help me.

[image: Here I have my function for the preview of the photo and the submit function]
[image]
[image: Here is my form]
[image: my multer setup]
[image: my API routes]
[image: the function that is used to edit the user info]

Sending the form gives me no error when I put a req.body.file in my edit function but then the image of my profile is undefined,
I also tried req.file[0].filename, which doesn't work either.

I would like that when the user uploads an image it is downloaded in my images folder and that it is also displayed on the user's profile

I thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when doing a put request you are sending your data in JSON not in form data. you need to do something like this

```
const onSubmit = () => {
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("firstName", firstName);
....
formData.append("avatar", avatar);
```

also FileReader.readAsDataURL return string but multer needs value of type File, so we need to directly store event.target.files[0] inside state so that multer can read it.

make sure you have express middleware

```
app.use(express.json());
```

not but the least `upload.single("avatar")` it should be the name of variable

hope these changes help you.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer, it works very well with what you give me, however I would like to make sure that the user can have a preview of what he is going to upload, how can I manage this in my handleImgUpload function? thank you you manage :)

Comment: HI, yes you can manage two states, one to store file and other to store readable buffer to preview the image to user.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, everything works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see your implementation for React `updateUser`, but looks like you are using the key `avatar` when uploading a file but accessing it via `image` key.

Also just use file Blob from HTMLInput

```js
const handleImgUpload = (e) => setAvatar(e.target.files[0])
```

Try to change your router to

```js
router.put('/update/:id', requiresAuth, upload.single('avatar'), updateUser)
```

and make sure you submit the form with Content-Type header `multipart/form-data`

Comment: Hello ! thank you for your answer I edit my post, I put my API call, I also tried to put avatar I still have the same error.

Comment: @furaxsme try to remove your readFile function and use file blob directly

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, everything works fine :)